Not able to run a trigger on Foreign Table to update local table using postgres_fdw
I've tried several variation and looked at examples of existing threads related to running triggers on foreign table and none have worked so far. The postgres_fdw documentation suggests setting the SHEMA path, which I've done (although I'm not sure if this is correct).
Here is a simple procedure to update a local db table whenever a change has taken place on the foreign table;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_budget2_updates()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
    SET search_path=public
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    -- Insert a log entry with the word "It works" 
    INSERT INTO public.log_table (log)
    VALUES ('It_works!');
    RETURN NEW; -- Return the updated row
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.log_budget2_updates()
    OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.log_budget2_updates() TO PUBLIC;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.log_budget2_updates() TO postgres;


-- Trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_all_changes
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.budget3
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.log_budget2_updates();

I'm using Postgres16
I am expecting that the public.log_table is updated with the words "It_works!".
I've tested this using a separate local test table and the same procedure and it works as expected.

UPDATE: The trigger also works when I run an update statement from within my local database on the foreign table (updates the remote table).
It seems that I am unable to see updates from the source (foreign) database. Is this a setting issue or a current limitation?

You should include the setup of your foreign table budget3

Actions taken directly on the source table do not 'fire' local triggers on the foreign table. The current documentation on triggers is not very clear.
For the trigger to work the action must be done directly on the foreign table (meaning within the same database where the Foreign table) resides.
In my use case, I have only read access to the table and needed to know when a change occurred. As a workaround, I made a copy of the table and created an agent to compare the 2 tables daily for changes, after which I modified the copy with those and then fired the triggers.
